# Verilog and condition for Always block

Tags: verilog, active-hdl

Im working on a project and after chasing down a bug i narrowed it down to it being caused by an Always block that doesnt trigger correctly.

```
module Counter(start,clk_len,done,clk,reset);     

    input [4:0] clk_len;
    input clk,start,reset;
    output done;
    reg [4:0] cntr_var = 0; reg start_val = 0; 
    assign done = !start_val;       
    reg test = 0;

    always @(reset){cntr_var,start_val} = 2'b0;

    always @(posedge start) begin
        start_val = start;
    end      

    always @((done and cntr_var == clk_len)) begin // <=== This is the source of the problem
        cntr_var = 0;
        start_val = 0; 
        test = 1;
    end             

    always @(clk and !reset) begin  
        if (start_val == 1 && cntr_var != clk_len)
                cntr_var = cntr_var + 1;
    end 

endmodule
```

One of the always blocks is supposed to trigger when `done` AND `(cntr_var == clk_len)`.

I tried using both `&&` and `and` as the logic operator. 
Why isnt this working?

Comment: What have written will not work at all, or of it does that would be an accident. You whole coding style is wrong. You have from top to bottom race conditions. I suggest you have a look at some real working Verilog code and see what they do. Start with one clocked section which also has the reset, and a second combinatorial section which uses `always @( * )`.

Comment: Well its not a standalone counter. The start signal comes in and tells the counter to start and once its done it has to signal it somehow back to the main module

Comment: you already have clocks and reset in your module. Please find up examples which use clocks and resets correctly and try to **completely** re-write you code to use correct style. The way you have it will not work. Start with modeling a simple stand-alone flip-flop.

Answer (score 3):

Your first big problem is `@(expression)` means *"wait until the expression has a value change"*. That change could be from 1➩0 or 0➩1. Typically one only uses `always @(posedge clk)` for synchronous logic, or `always @(*)` for combinational logic. (`always_comb` in SystemVerilog)

Your other problem is you should only be making assignments to a particular variable from one, *and only one* always block.